# Eclipse 2020 with Wild Web Dev - problem with Javascript colors

Tags: javascript, eclipse, editor

I'm running Eclipse 2020 for JEE dev, with Wild Web Dev plugin installed. I open .js files using Generic Text Editor (the only one I found that does formatting). However, the colors are difficult to see, and I cannot find a way to change color settings for the Generic Text editor:

[image: see a snapshot]

Also, the colors do NOT correspond to anything set in Preferences -> Web > JavaScript or Clent-side JavaScript configurations.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not working? https://dvteclipse.com/documentation/e/How_do_I_change_the_background_color_of_the_Editor.3F.html#:~:text=Go%20to%20Window%20%3E%20Preferences%2C%20then,default%20checkbox%20must%20be%20unchecked).

Comment: That does work, but i was hoping to change the text, not the background. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In the editor **right-click** and choose ***Switch to Theme... > Light*** (which which is more similar to the default Java color scheme than the default *Solarized Light* theme shown in your screenshot).

The *Generic Text Editor* themes for languages supported by language servers can be configured in *Window > **Preferences: TextMate > Theme***. You might also create your own theme CSS file (e.g. [based on an existing theme](https://github.com/eclipse/tm4e/tree/master/org.eclipse.tm4e.ui/themes)) and add it in this preference page.

Note, the *Web > (Client-side) JavaScript* preferences pages refer to the [WTP JavaScript editor](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/webtools.jsdt), not to the JavaScript editor of [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) you are using.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. Changes in TextMate, at a glance, do not seem to have an effect, but i will try again.

Comment: Did you tried to switch from the default _Solarized Light_ theme to the _Light_ theme via right-click menu? Maybe the _Light_ theme is what you are looking for and you don't need to change anything in the preferences.

Comment: That is exactly it - thank you so much ! No, i did not try it before, did not know that option existed.  Changing the themes in TextMate does not work though.